# How to generate pipes (tubes) maze with some limitations

Tags: php, algorithm, maps, game-physics, maze

I have a map with size of 10x10.

Each map cell can be empty or contain a pipe segment. Segment types are: straight pipe, elbow pipe, t pipe, and cross pipe. Each segment can of course be rotated and flipped in which other segments can stack onto it.

I have fixed starting and ending cells - one at [1,5] and the second at [10,5].

I need to create a path from the starting point to the ending point, but there are some parameters which need to be passed to the generator:

1. Allowed types: for example, only straight and elbow segments could be used. Cross and t are not allowed.
2. Allowed number of used elements. For example, from 15 to 25. So generator MUST generate path of this range - not less than 15 and not more than 25.

I see two strategies in general:

1. Create a generic maze (not considering it consists of tubes) and then "translate" cells to relevant tube segments. But I can't control type of segments and can't control number of elements.
2. Iteratively add segments to the current position. For example I have source at [1,5]. I can add any allowed type segment to [2,5]. Then I can add any allowed type segment to [2, 4], [2, 6] or [3, 5] (randomly) and so on. But the problems are how to control number of used elements and how to make sure I'm coming to the ending point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)? They might be a good point to start.

Comment: You mean, you need to generate the shortest path? Or any path which satisfies the constraints will do?

Comment: I need to generate any path which consist of fixed number of elements, "enter" and "exit" are fixed. So the shortest path will be set of straight tubes. But I need to make it more complicated using additional segments (T-like, L-like and +).